# why can't i compare strings

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, strcmp

What the program is supposed to do:

Gets a DNA code from the user

Gets 10 3-letter words

If the combination of any 2 3-letter corresponds with the DNA code program prints it.

I hope I managed to explain it well.

I don't know why it crashes, but I guess it is about the double pointer thing I tried to do. Or the strcmp thing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char * dna;
    char ** sample;
    int i,j,len;

    dna = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*20);

    gets(dna);
    sample = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        sample[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
    }

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        gets(sample[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            strcat(sample[i],sample[j]);
            if(strcmp(sample[i], dna)==0)
            {
                puts(sample[i]);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        free(sample[i]);
    }

    free(sample);
    free(dna);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I don't know why it chrashes" -- consider using a debugger may be

Comment: What is the input  you are giving to the program?

Comment: `strcat(sample[i],sample[j]);` How many characters do you expect `sample[i]` to hold?

Comment: You don't provide memory for 10 words. And the memory you provide is only for 1 letter words.

Comment: i make every sample[i] a string arrray and make it hold 3 letters

Comment: sample = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*)*10); -- i provide memory for 10 words

Comment: Note that [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Comment: No; the `sample` array elements can only hold 2 characters plus the terminating null because you allocate `sample[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*3);`. You can't safely concatenate the strings (`strcat()`) unless both source and destination have 1-character strings. You're not paying enough attention to memory. C doesn't pay attention to how you use memory either — and does what you tell it assuming you know what you're doing. That, I regret to say, makes it hard for beginners who don't know what they're doing. But you need to allocate more space, and you need to forget that `gets()` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your memory calculations are wrong, memory allocated for `sample[i]` and `sample[j]` are exactly the same, yet you are trying to concatenate to `sample[i]` which is not the correct thing

```
strcat(sample[i],sample[j]);
```

On a completely different note from the manual of `gets`

*Never use `gets()`.  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters `gets()` will read, and  because `gets()` will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer security. Use `fgets()` instead.*